# Mysql locking entire table when using 'in' predicate

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a strange problem with Mysql locking the entire table when making a query with a particular 'in' predicate.

This is the table concerned:

```
create table TableA ( 
USERID bigint(20) unsigned not null, 
BLOBID tinyint unsigned not null, 
blob_contents mediumblob not null, 
primary key(ID1, ID2)) engine=innodb default charset=latin1;
```

There is a composite primary key set of (USERID, BLOBID). Here is some example data:

```
{[1, 1, <blob>], 
[1, 2, <blob>], 
[1, 3, <blob>], 
[2, 1, <blob>], 
[2, 2, <blob>]}
```

Say I want to get the data for blobs 1,2 and 3 for user 2 (I don't know at this point that there is no row for the blob with id 3 for this user). This is the query I would run:

```
select * from TableA where USERID = 2 and BLOBID in (1, 2, 3) for update;
```

The query returns blobs 1 and 2 for user2 and finds nothing for blobid 3. Unfortunately even with the primary key it seems that this query locks the entire table. You can see the join type is 'ALL' when explaining the query:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TABLEA | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    7 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

When I remove '3' from the in clause, Mysql correctly uses the primary key and locks just the 2 rows required:

```
select * from TableA where USERID = 2 and BLOBID in (1, 2) for update;

+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TableA | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 9       | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to make this query and yet only lock the rows actually returned by the query?

Comment: Is the `for update` lock really needed on the query?

Comment: Yes the point is that I want to query some data, modify it and write it back within a single transaction atomically. Maybe there's way to do this other than for update that I don't know about?

Comment: I cannot understand how you can come up with BLOBID set (1,2,3) for that user since that BLOBID does not exist in the table. You are retrieving BLOBIDs from another table? If so, maybe you should use Foreign key constraints which are supported by the InnoDB engine http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Strange thing is, I observe different behaviour [on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2718d/3).  What version of MySQL are you using?